# Setting MS Word Paper Size to PostScript Custom Page Size programmatically

Tags: vba, windows, powershell, ms-word

### The Scene

What I am trying to do is programmatically convert an MS word (.docx) file to a PostScript file (.ps). I am doing this by creating a PostScript printer with one of the default PostScript printer drivers bundled with MS Windows and then printing the Word doc using this printer from Word. The catch is I am trying to do this with a custom page size, i.e. the height and width do not match any of the standard paper sizes ie. A4, A3, Letter etc

If I do this manually in MS Word everything works as expected BUT only if I set the Page Setup paper size to *PostScript Custom Page Size*. If its not set to this value the output page size is one of the pre-defined page sizes i.e. B5 (default).

[image: Word default paper size - B5]

But if I set the Paper size to *PostScript Custom Page Size* and then print with the same printer the output file is the correct height and width as set on the document, in this case, 181mm x 260mm

[image: PostScript Custom Page Size]

### The Problem

I cant find a way to programmatically set the Page Setup Paper size value to the value "PostScript Custom Page Size", and if I dont set this value then the custom height and width are ignored.

### What have I already tried

I have tried doing the following:

1. Using the Word COM objects in PowerShell

   ```
   ...
   #create com object
   $word = New-Object -com Word.Application

   #dont open word UI
   $word.visible = $false

   #open input file
   $doc = $word.Documents.Open($inputfile)

   $width = [double]$word.MillimetersToPoints($widthInMM)
   $height = [double]$word.MillimetersToPoints($heightInMM)

   #set page setup width and height
   $doc.PageSetup.PageWidth = $width
   $doc.PageSetup.PageHeight = $height

   #save the changes
   $doc.Save()

   $pBackGround = 0
   $pAppend = 0
   $pRange = 0

   #print the file to default printer (i.e. ps printer)
   $doc.printout([ref]$pBackGround,[ref]$pAppend,[ref]$pRange,[ref]$outputfile)
   ...
   ```

   Looking at the MS docs, the PageSetup object has a [PageSize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.pagesetup.papersize), which says the following on the page

> Setting the PageHeight or PageWidth property changes the PaperSize property to wdPaperCustom.

And looking at the PaperSize property its an enum, WdPaperSize, which has the following [values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdpapersize)
   But as you can see by the quote above, if you set the height and width the paper size will be set to the wdPaperCustom value. BUT this is not the same as *PostScript Custom Page Size*, which from what I have read this is not one of the valid enum values.

2. Pure PowerShell
   The only way to print a word (docx) file is using the Start-Process command with verb Print. If you dont want to use the default printer you can pipe it to the out-printer command

```
Start-Process $file -verb Print | out-printer -name "PrinterName"
```

This prints the document, but actually opens up Word to print which has 2 problems

a. You have to manually specify the output file name

b. It still uses the MS Word default page settings

3. Recording a VBA Macro: Recording setting the correct paper size doesn't record setting it to *PostScript Custom Page Size*. This is what the macro looks like

   ```
   With Selection.PageSetup
   .LineNumbering.Active = False
   .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
   .TopMargin = MillimetersToPoints(13)
   .BottomMargin = MillimetersToPoints(13)
   .LeftMargin = MillimetersToPoints(13)
   .RightMargin = MillimetersToPoints(13)
   .Gutter = MillimetersToPoints(3)
   .HeaderDistance = MillimetersToPoints(12.5)
   .FooterDistance = MillimetersToPoints(12.5)
   .PageWidth = MillimetersToPoints(181)
   .PageHeight = MillimetersToPoints(260)
   .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
   .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
   .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
   .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = True
   .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
   .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
   .SuppressEndnotes = False
   .MirrorMargins = True
   .TwoPagesOnOne = False
   .BookFoldPrinting = False
   .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
   .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
   .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
   End With
   ```

   As you can see above there is no mention of the paper size being set to any value.
   I haven't tried this in c# or .NET because they all seem to use the COM Object API which reverts to my issues in 1.

I think the issue is that Word seems to ignore the printer settings, even [Microsoft seems to admit this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/printer-settings-not-used)

With the printer I am creating a PostScript printer defining the specific paper size, height and width, but MS Word when printing ignores these settings and uses its own default settings. Even though the height and width of the pages in Word are set correctly its the paper size property that seems to be messing things up.

So the only logical thing I can think of is remove Word from the mix. The issue there is I cant find anything that handles Word properly. You can just send the file to the printer say in PowerShell, but it seems to still open Word and use the Word settings again.

Does anyone know of a way around this or a way to programmatically set the paper size to *PostScript Custom Page Size*

Comment: I can't help, only offer another tidbit of information to what you've already gathered: Printers/printer drivers can add entries to these kinds of lists. If no postscript printer is available (driver installed) the entry you're looking for isn't available in the list. That's why there's no `wd`-enumerator available.

Comment: Since I have no access to such a printer I can't test the only approach that occurs to me: Each `wdPaperSize`-enum has a numerical equivalent You might test setting the property with values "outside" the enum range (starting with 42) to see 1) Whether Word accepts the values and 2) if yes, which option in *your* listing the value corresponds to. Note that, even if this works, the value that corresponds on your machine may not be the same as on other machines... (Note that I'd test in VBA since that would be faster and more "immediate" than out-of-process code.)

Comment: It might make a difference which printer is set to be active in Word at the time the macro runs. In a quick test, after setting the active printer to the Microsoft Print to PDF driver included with Windows 10, a page setup macro like your second posting does change the paper size in Word 2019. You can set the active printer using Application.ActivePrinter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.activeprinter

Comment: @CindyMeister - thanks for the tidbits. For me the printer is installed, but assumed that an enum was fixed based on the MS docs, but I did notice the enums have numerical values yes, I haven't tried using values > 42 to see if that works, issue with this is that it may work on one machine but not every machine - no guarantee values will be the same, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: @JohnKorchok - I have my printer that i am using set as the default printer, so its the active printer, also I have used while testing to activate the printer too before running any logic. Its not about changing the paper size, but changing it to a specific value which is not part of the MS enums.

Comment: Printer settings are not part of Word. Word gets the possible settings from the active printer driver. So if your driver doesn't support that setting, neither can Word.

Comment: The driver can support it, because if I manually go and print the document in Word and set the paper size to Custom PostScript Page Size then everything works as expected, but you cant do that programmatically. That is what the problem was. I was not trying to set printer settings in Word.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in how I solved this, well I say solved but its more of a different solution to achieve the same outcome.

I still have not found a way to change the paper size to *PostScript Custom Page Size* but instead I was able to get the paper size to change based on the width and height set on the document (as per the documentation), which feels like a better solution to me. So these are the steps I took to solve it:

1. Chose a PostScript driver that I want to use. I decided to use the *Xerox PS Class Driver*, which is a PostScript driver bundled with Windows.
2. Find where the driver is located. Printer drivers on Windows are located in following directory

   ```
    C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\
   ```

   You can located the driver you are after using the following grep like command

   ```
    findstr /S /I /M /C:"Xerox PS Class Driver" C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\*.*
   ```
3. Edited the PPD file and added the paper size that I am looking for and set it as the default paper size. The most import part to update is *PageSize*, it provides an invocation value to invoke supported page sizes. I removed all other page sizes and just added the one I was after, calling it *Custom*

   ```
   *% Page Size
   *OpenUI *PageSize: PickOne
   *OrderDependency: 40 AnySetup *PageSize
   *DefaultPageSize: Custom
   *PageSize Custom/Custom: "featurebegin{<< /PageSize [369 522] >> setpagedevice}featurecleanup"
   *CloseUI: *PageSize
   ```

The values in this snippet are in points so you need to convert them. Above I am using 130 mm x 184 mm ~ 369 points x 522 points

More information about PPD files in its [spec document](https://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/5003.PPD_Spec_v4.3.pdf)

4. Added a printer using this adjusted printer driver

   ```
   Add-Printer -Name "PrinterName" -DriverName "Xerox PS Class Driver" -PortName "file:"
   ```

   To keep things simple I named my printer the size of the page i.e. *130x184* so its easy to use programmatically
5. Created a new form in the print server properties which matches my new paper size. To do this open Devices and Printers > Click your printer > Click Printer Server Properties in top menu > Check "Create a new form" checkbox > Add a name and set your dimenions > Save Form

[image]

6. Using my PowerShell code above, when the page dimensions of my document are set correctly and my new printer is set as default, the new form I just created above is found because our printer now handles the new page dimensions. In my script above I am actually setting the printer as default printer on Windows I just left that part out, so either add it to the script or manually set the printer as default printer.
7. Printed a PostScript file using the new printer

Hope this helps someone else too

Comment: Thanks for sharing - thumbs up!